# How to group/clean group of scattered points based on their distance and attributes?

Tags: qgis, grouping, mapillary

I downloaded traffic signs from [Mapillary API](https://www.mapillary.com/developer/api-documentation/). I found that many of these points represent the same real life entity, but they are scattered in the map. Since they are distinguished by their category and they are relatively close together I thought that I could try to group them to have only one object. (For now it is fine to set aside that the position won't be the same as in real life.) I am looking for tools to do this either in QGIS or PostgreSQL. (I understand that this should be two different questions, but I will modify the question according to the answer.) I tried to find plugins and functions to solve this but I did not find any. In a way the data is already clustered so I assume it's not a clustering problem.

Example:
The "One way street" signs at the bottom left, and the "No entry" signs at upper right corner are the representation of the same real world traffic signs. Instead of those multiple ones, I would like to have only one.

[image]

I am aware that this could mess up the data in a way where different real life signs get grouped together into one object, but I will take that risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a point layer with buildings. It has an attribute called **objekttypnr** which is the building typecode.

I use st_clusterdbscan to assign each point a cluster id, then group by the id and typecode, and calculate the centroids of each group to get a mean point

Change the table, field names and 500 (the distance to cluster by).

```sql
drop table public.buildings_clustered;
create table public.buildings_clustered as

with clusters as 
            (select objekttypnr, st_clusterdbscan(geom, 500, 2) over() clusterid, geom
            from lmv.byggnadsverk_sverige_byggnadspunkt as building)

select objekttypnr, st_centroid(st_union(geom)) from clusters where clusterid is not null group by objekttypnr, clusterid
union 
select objekttypnr, geom from clusters where clusterid is null
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I think I kind of did the same in QGIS. I created a buffer for the points with a suitable distance, dissolved by their category, and created a centroid for them. But if interpret correctly, your sql code does somewhat the same, without the buffer.

Comment: Nice! It should give you a similar result. You can also use the same logic as the sql code using QGIS with [dbscanclustering](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisdbscanclustering)